# Configure PostgreSQL to work for only LOCALHOST or specified ip + port

Tags: postgresql, configuration, ipconfig

I want to configure PostgreSQL to accept connections only from a specified IP. It should not accept requests from any other IP.

Comment: Pg version? OS? Do you mean localhost only? Or "accept connections only from one named non-local IP address" ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The following example pg_hba.conf allows local and a specified IP to have privileged login, but rejects others.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     trust
host    testdb          testuser      192.168.1.1/32            md5
host    all             all           0.0.0.0/0                 reject
```

Answer (score 18):

The easiest way is to make PostgreSQL listen only on `localhost` for incoming connections. The relevant parameter is `listen_addresses` in `postgresql.conf`. The doc is [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-connection.html).

Answer (score 6):

Check the [pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file in the data folder of PostgreSQL. This is the client authentication configuration file.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    testdb           testuser      192.168.1.1               md5
local   testdb           all                                     md5
```

Add the above to the pg_hba.conf file

Comment: Note that PostgreSQL will still accept TCP socket connections to its port from any interface it is bound to via `listen_addresses` in `postgresql.conf`, it just won't let them authenticate. If you want to prevent even a TCP handshake, you'll need to use `iptables`.