# Pyramid Postgresql Connection Issue

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

Moving from SQLITE3 to Postgresql (psql (PostgreSQL) 9.4.5) in Pyramid

I have been using `sqlite3` to access a `sqlalchemy` database. I have developed a `pyramid` web framework and sqlite3 has been working. However, I wanted to move away from using `sqlite3` and instead use `postgresql` for the db. I am new to this and am trying to figure out if I am missing a step.

I followed [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695220/pyramid-postgresql-connection) in downloading `psycopg2` (adding it to setup.py) changing the `development.ini` file from: 
`sqlalchemy.url = sqlite:////Users/ack/code/venv/NotssDB/notssdb/notssdb`

to:
`sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://ack:password@localhost:5432/notssdb` 
I installed postgres via [this site](https://www.codefellows.org/blog/three-battle-tested-ways-to-install-postgresql#macosx) using mac osx.

With that said, when I startup the app `pserve development.ini` ...the database is not connecting or loading. When I use the `sqlite` url, the database connects.

What might I be missing?

**development.ini** 
in pyramid:

```
sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://ack:password@localhost:5432/notssdb

# By default, the toolbar only appears for clients from IP addresses
# '127.0.0.1' and '::1'.
# debugtoolbar.hosts = 127.0.0.1 ::1

###
# wsgi server configuration
###

[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 5432
```

`postgresql.conf`

```
# - Connection Settings -

#listen_addresses = 'localhost'     # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
#port = 5432                # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
```

postgres server log:

```
LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
```

Do I have to change the [postgres config file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)? (A [stacks question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753296/configure-postgresql-to-work-for-only-localhost-or-specified-ip-port) refers to it too)... I saw this in `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all           0.0.0.0/0                trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     ack                                trust
#host    replication     ack        127.0.0.1/32            trust
#host    replication     ack        ::1/128                 trust
```

Using the terminal, this connects me to the DB on postgres:

```
psql -h localhost -d notssdb -p 5432
```

## NEW

*postgresql server is automatically launched*

**How I launch Pyramid app:**

```
$ python setup.py develop #installs packages 
$ initialize_notssweb_db development.ini # --db Session--
$ pserve development.ini  #terminal: --db Session-- Starting server in PID 3501. serving on http://0.0.0.0:5432
```

Checking the server:

```
$  pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres status
pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 701)
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5/bin/postgres "-D" "/usr/local/var/postgres" "-r" "/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log"
```

Comment: Could you please edit the question to include relevant error messages of "not loading" and also check PostgreSQL log files.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I wish I got a `not loading` prompt... I am getting `No data received ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.`

Comment: You need to get a Python traceback error, not what your web server says. It is in the console of your Pyramid application or in the log files.

Comment: Also different operating systems configure different PostgreSQL versions differently so include information about this.

Comment: Also if there is no password on PSQL the connection string should look like  `postgresql://localhost/notssdb`

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I'm not getting a Python traceback error or anything in the logfiles. Using `psql (PostgreSQL) 9.4.5`

Comment: I think we need to be able to see how you initialize your application, how you create your view and how you call this view with your browser, where your log output goes, does your log output work without database setup, at least. Without good diagnosing information it is very hard to tell what could be going on here.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa when I use the sqlite db url (shown above) the whole system works and I am able to see my db and interact with it based on the view config... Here is a quick view of the `initilize...` and `view config`: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f1921dd5eade586a830d

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I think it might be the conf file (see above)

Comment: I still don't see *the actual Python error*. Information is good, but there is no error to speak of. You need to capture the Python error on the connecition or wherever it happens and have it in the question, or helping is pretty futile.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa what is the best way to capture the error? It doesn't seem to be connecting with the pyramid app

Comment: Add the steps to the question how you launch your Pyramid and app how you follow it.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa added how I launch Pyramid

Comment: When you start a pserve and try to open a page what it prints to console? If it doesn't print anything then add some debug prints to your code to see where it stops. It should yield an error in some point if it cannot connect to database.

Comment: It just prints `: --db Session-- Start` as shown above which is from the database.

Comment: Ok, gotcha! Let me think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92590/discussion-between-mikko-ohtamaa-and-thesayhey).

Comment: Yes! I can. But not by computer. Can we later today or tomorrow ? You're the best @MikkoOhtamaa!

Comment: Ok. I might not be on Stackoverflow but you can find me on irc.freenode.net IRC server on #pyramid channel under nick Moo (something). Mention my nick in the public chat and it should give me an alert if I am on the computer.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Thank you for your continuous help... I changed the `port` today and used your recommended: `sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://localhost/NOTSSDB` and it suddenly started working. Maybe a mac os bug? idk... but seems to be working now.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is the only problem, but it looks like you have port conflict. You try to launch pyramid app (via pserve) on the same port postgresql listens by default (5432).

```
[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 5432
```

Port parameter here is for pserve listen port, change it to 8000 or something.

Comment: Yes a change of port allowed `postgres` to interact with pyramid. I figured that out by accident, but your explanation is better for those who may come into the same issue. Thank you Sergey.